# Using toJSON or not with Snapshot testing with Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I am new to React, and I am testing my components. When implementing snapshot testing I have found these two approaches:

**Approach 1**

```js
import React from 'react'
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'
import Projects from './Projects'

it('renders Projects component properly', () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(<Projects />)
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

**Approach 2**

```js
import React from 'react'
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'
import Projects from './Projects'

it('renders Projects component properly', () => {
  const component = renderer.create(<Projects />)
  const tree = component.toJSON()
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

Is it important to call `toJSON` in the component (approach 2) or can you just pass it directly to check `toMatchSnapshot` (approach 1)? Can somebody explain me the difference between both approaches in terms of performance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR**

When `toMatchSnapshot` matcher is used `toJSON` is called on the object passed to `expect`. It is a part of some kind of chain of checks that may have a neglectable, for a vast majority of real cases, performance impact. I would suggest calling `toJSON` just to follow "explicit is better than implicit" principle and the fact that the inner behavior is subject to change.

**Explanation**

The [matcher uses](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/4a59daa8715bde6a1b085ff7f4140f3a337045aa/packages/jest-snapshot/src/index.ts#L364) SnapshotStates [`match` method](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/4a59daa8715bde6a1b085ff7f4140f3a337045aa/packages/jest-snapshot/src/State.ts#L188) that [serializes](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/4a59daa8715bde6a1b085ff7f4140f3a337045aa/packages/jest-snapshot/src/State.ts#L210) object. [`serialize`](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/4a59daa8715bde6a1b085ff7f4140f3a337045aa/packages/jest-snapshot/src/utils.ts#L156) just calls pretty-format with a set of plugins.

This is the entry point of [pretty-format](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/4a59daa8715bde6a1b085ff7f4140f3a337045aa/packages/pretty-format/src/index.ts#L493), I've added comments there:

```
function prettyFormat(
  val: unknown,
  options?: PrettyFormat.OptionsReceived,
): string {
  if (options) {
    validateOptions(options);
    if (options.plugins) {
      const plugin = findPlugin(options.plugins, val);
      /* When val is a result of `toJSON` call 
         it has a $$typeof: Symbol.for('react.test.json') field so  
         it is handled by ReactTestComponent plugin in this point */
      if (plugin !== null) {
        return printPlugin(plugin, val, getConfig(options), '', 0, []);
      }
    }
  }

  // When `toJSON` is not called `printBasicValue` is invoked but is it pointless
  const basicResult = printBasicValue(
    val,
    getPrintFunctionName(options),
    getEscapeRegex(options),
    getEscapeString(options),
  );
  if (basicResult !== null) {
    return basicResult;
  }

  return printComplexValue(val, getConfig(options), '', 0, []);
}
```

[`printBasicValue`](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/4a59daa8715bde6a1b085ff7f4140f3a337045aa/packages/pretty-format/src/index.ts#L97) simply performs a set of checks, all of them fail for an object, so the [`printComplexValue`](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/4a59daa8715bde6a1b085ff7f4140f3a337045aa/packages/pretty-format/src/index.ts#L176) takes its turn.
Here is a fragment where `.toJSON()` is called.

```
  if (
    config.callToJSON &&
    !hitMaxDepth &&
    val.toJSON &&
    typeof val.toJSON === 'function' &&
    !hasCalledToJSON
  ) {
    return printer(val.toJSON(), config, indentation, depth, refs, true);
  }
```

`printer` finds a plugin and invokes it at the very beggining so it does not matter.

```
  const plugin = findPlugin(config.plugins, val);
  if (plugin !== null) {
    return printPlugin(plugin, val, config, indentation, depth, refs);
  }
```

You can notice that calling `toJSON` may be disabled by setting a config option or by some other conditions that I believe do not matter for the case of snapshot, but still.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer and your detailed explanation.